# How to map individual servlet to spring framework and test it's doPost method using unit testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, mocking, annotations

I have implemented `fileupload` functionality using apache commons file upload library and implemented logic in doPost method of the servlet. Now I want to unit test `doPost` method fo the servlet and also how can I wire this servlet with the spring framework?

There is one suggestion of using one variable with @Autowire annotation in the servlet, not sure if that will work.

Any suggestions or thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you writing servlets, if you're using spring?

Comment: I wanted to use Apache Commons File Upload Libary and so have created servlet for implementing file upload functionality

Comment: So why not do that through Spring? http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart

Comment: I agree on that point but right now i have already implemented the functionality and so is there a way to include that in spring framework and do unit testing on doPost method?

Comment: Would reimplementing it as a Spring controller be that much work?  Failing that, you can wrap the existing servlet using a `ServletWrappingController` (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/ServletWrappingController.html)

Comment: are there any other suggestions?

Comment: @skaffman let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1429/discussion-between-rachel-and-skaffman)

Comment: we can use mock object using mockito or easyMocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can include spring application context in a servlet by using a util class.

`WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(ServletContext sc)`

this would give you an instalce of the spring application context.. here on you can call spring services in your servlet.

refer [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html) for documentation.